# How to process 10000 and more python dict data?

Tags: python, data-processing

Hello all i have an issue with processing more dict data on python 
it's taking too much time to complete.

is any other way to process the data fast.

Dict data example(10000 more having but put 5 of them here)

```
data=[
{
"id": "30421",
"age": "35",
"email": "email_7816@gmail.com",
"pref_location": "50",
"preference_id": "2",
"sub_preference_id": "99",
"preference": "a:5:{s:3:\"cul\";a:4: 
{i:0;i:17;i:1;i:43;i:2;i:51;i:3;i:19;}s:3:\"int\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:16;i:1;i:25;i:2;i:100;}s:3:\"edu\";a:2: 
{i:0;i:70;i:1;i:98;}s:3:\"age\";a:1:{i:0;i:25;}s:3:\"job\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:14;i:1;i:24;i:2;i:101;}}"
},
{
"id": "30421",
"age": "35",
"email": "email_7816@gmail.com",
"pref_location": "50",
"preference_id": "2",
"sub_preference_id": "99",
"preference": "a:5:{s:3:\"cul\";a:4: 
{i:0;i:17;i:1;i:43;i:2;i:51;i:3;i:19;}s:3:\"int\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:16;i:1;i:25;i:2;i:100;}s:3:\"edu\";a:2: 
{i:0;i:70;i:1;i:98;}s:3:\"age\";a:1:{i:0;i:25;}s:3:\"job\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:14;i:1;i:24;i:2;i:101;}}"
},
{
"id": "30421",
"age": "35",
"email": "email_7816@gmail.com",
"pref_location": "50",
"preference_id": "2",
"sub_preference_id": "99",
"preference": "a:5:{s:3:\"cul\";a:4: 
{i:0;i:17;i:1;i:43;i:2;i:51;i:3;i:19;}s:3:\"int\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:16;i:1;i:25;i:2;i:100;}s:3:\"edu\";a:2: 
{i:0;i:70;i:1;i:98;}s:3:\"age\";a:1:{i:0;i:25;}s:3:\"job\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:14;i:1;i:24;i:2;i:101;}}"
},
{
"id": "30421",
"age": "35",
"email": "email_7816@gmail.com",
"pref_location": "50",
"preference_id": "2",
"sub_preference_id": "99",
"preference": "a:5:{s:3:\"cul\";a:4: 
{i:0;i:17;i:1;i:43;i:2;i:51;i:3;i:19;}s:3:\"int\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:16;i:1;i:25;i:2;i:100;}s:3:\"edu\";a:2: 
{i:0;i:70;i:1;i:98;}s:3:\"age\";a:1:{i:0;i:25;}s:3:\"job\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:14;i:1;i:24;i:2;i:101;}}"
},
{
"id": "30421",
"age": "35",
"email": "email_7816@gmail.com",
"pref_location": "50",
"preference_id": "2",
"sub_preference_id": "99",
"preference": "a:5:{s:3:\"cul\";a:4: 
{i:0;i:17;i:1;i:43;i:2;i:51;i:3;i:19;}s:3:\"int\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:16;i:1;i:25;i:2;i:100;}s:3:\"edu\";a:2: 
{i:0;i:70;i:1;i:98;}s:3:\"age\";a:1:{i:0;i:25;}s:3:\"job\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:14;i:1;i:24;i:2;i:101;}}"
},
{
"id": "30421",
"age": "35",
"email": "email_7816@gmail.com",
"pref_location": "50",
"preference_id": "2",
"sub_preference_id": "99",
"preference": "a:5:{s:3:\"cul\";a:4: 
{i:0;i:17;i:1;i:43;i:2;i:51;i:3;i:19;}s:3:\"int\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:16;i:1;i:25;i:2;i:100;}s:3:\"edu\";a:2: 
{i:0;i:70;i:1;i:98;}s:3:\"age\";a:1:{i:0;i:25;}s:3:\"job\";a:3: 
{i:0;i:14;i:1;i:24;i:2;i:101;}}"
},
```

I need get user by preferred location age and other constraints

example for preferred location

```
def group_by_pref_loc(data):
    pre_loc=[]
    grp=[]

    for p in data:
        pre_loc.append(p["pref_location"])
        pre_loc=list(set(pre_loc))

    for p in pre_loc:
        sample=[]
        for q in data:
            if q["pref_location"]==p:
                sample.append(q)       
        grp.append(sample)
    return grp
```

not this function only, 
my question is how to process large amount of data in a certain time 
suggest me library or web platform.

note* I'm using linux with Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G2030 @ 3.00GHz

Comment: Get rid of the outter loop and use `if if q["pref_location"] in pre_loc` instead, also don't use a list for it, sets are much faster.

Comment: on top of @DKlaus suggestion: 1. try a comprehension instead of a loop (with set). 2. make a function that yields results 3. try `dataset` package with sql statement for your query

Comment: 4. make a pandas dataframe based on your data?

Comment: 10000 records is not "bigdata". It's a few MB at most.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a course in data structures and algorithms. I'm not usually this blunt but your first loop is awful. For every dict in the `data` list you append the location to `pref_loc`, convert that list to a set to eliminate duplicates, then convert the set back to a list. Do you not see the obvious redundant operations? Just declare `pre_loc` as a set and add to it. In fact, you can do this with a generator which is considerably more efficient:

```
pre_loc = set(p["pref_location"] for p in data)
```

And because a set is an iterable just like a list there is no need to coerce it to a list in order to use it in your second loop.

There are even more succinct and efficient ways to do this. For example, use `itertools.groupby()`.